# Storing Refresh Token In JavaScript, Getting New Access Token

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have a ASP.NET Web API that returns an OAuth2 bearer token upon login.  I plan to store the refresh token in a cookie via JavaScript.  Where in my JS should I check if the access token is expired to fetch a new one...right before each subsequent API call that requires authentication or on some sort of timer loop?  This will be an async web app, so I didn't think a timer loop would be ideal.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not do that, if you can access your cookie in javascript it means any XSS script can hijack it. Localstorage is not a safe place either.

I would recommend storing the token in a secure http-only cookie right after the token has been generated on the server, and append that cookie to the response.

If you use WebAPI 2 with oAuth, in your authorizationServer provider you can override the TokenEndPointReponse

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Called when a request to the Token endpoint is finished and gonna be sent back to the client
    /// We intercept the token and force the client to write a cookie containing the token value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context)
    {

        // We set our auth cookie configuration
        var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
        {
            HttpOnly = true, // immune to JS manipulation
            Secure = insertMagicLogicHere(), // we set the cookie to secure in production environment
            Path = "/",
            Domain = ".mycooldomain.com",
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(GlobalAuthSettings.AuthServerOptions.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan.TotalMinutes)
        };

        var refreshTokenId = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:refreshTokenId");

        // We build the authentication object to store in our cookie
        var ourTokenObject = new AuthCookie
        {
            username = context.Properties.Dictionary["userName"],
            token = context.AccessToken,
            useRefreshTokens = true,
            refreshtoken = refreshTokenId
        };

        // We send it back 
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("mySecureCookie", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ourTokenObject), cookieOptions);

        return base.TokenEndpointResponse(context);
    }
```

Then in javascript you need to make sure the cookie is sent with each request.
You can setup some Owin Middleware to intercept requests, parse the token from the cookie and set the token to the Authorization Header.

To refresh the token you can configure an Http Interceptor that will automatically refresh the token if you receive a 401 and retry the request if the refreshtoken has been successful.

Here is some code in Angular

```
    //#region Private members

    var _retryHttpRequest = function (config, deferred) {
        $rootScope.httpRetries++;
        console.log('autorefresh');
        $http = $http || $injector.get('$http') || $injector.post('$http');
        $http(config).then(
        function (success) {
            $rootScope.httpRetries--;
            deferred.resolve(success);
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("Error in response", rejection);
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
    };

    var _refreshToken = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // refresh_token=refreshToken because the refresh_token is serialized in the http cookie and not accessible in javascript, the refreshToken is however stored in the cookie so we can resolve that server side
        var data = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=refreshToken&client_id=" + appState.clientId;
        $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');
        $http.post(authUrl + '/token', data, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }).error(function (err, status) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    //#endregion Private members

    //#region Public members

    function _request(config) {
        config.withCredentials = true; // forces angular to send cookies in each request
        return config;
    }

    // intercept response errors and refresh token if need be
    function _responseError(rejection) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (rejection.status === 401 || rejection.status === 403) {
            if ($rootScope.httpRetries < 2) {
                console.log("calling refreshToken()");
                _refreshToken().then(function (response) {
                    console.log("token refreshed, retrying to connect");
                    // retry the request if the token was successfully refreshed
                    _retryHttpRequest(rejection.config, deferred);
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log("_refreshToken error", error);
                    deferred.reject(rejection);
                    window.location.reload(true);
                });
            }
            else {
                console.log("_refreshToken error", error);
                deferred.reject(rejection);
                window.location.reload(true);
            }

        } else {
            console.log("Error in response", rejection);
            deferred.reject(rejection);
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    //#endregion Public members
```

Hope this helps.