# How to update outlook 2.0 API token using refresh-token?

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-restapi

I have next situation:
Main authentication flow happens on server, then client side obtains these data, since that moment I wanna client be able to update token by itself. It's seems there is all needed data on client(access_token, refresh_token), but I can't figure out how to organize request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token route.

First I tried to get json response:

```
$.ajax({
  url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=refresh_token&scope=openid%20profile%20offline%20access%20user.read%20mail.read%20contacts.read%20calendars.read&client_id=client&client_secret=secret`,
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    'Host': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  success: function(data) {
    ...
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    ...
  }
});
```

After that I figured out that it's only possible to get this data with redirect, is it correct? If it is, can someone produce an example of how to implement this, looks like it's needed to create an iframe and handle authorization somehow. Thanks.

**UPDATED:**
as [Alina Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10252988/alina-li) pointed in comment to her answer, there is a solution right in the official doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, you could using refresh-token through the below code:

```
var data = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=refreshToken&client_id=" + appState.clientId;
        $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');
        $http.post(authUrl + '/token', data, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function (response) {

        }).error(function (err, status) {

        });
```

You don’t need to add `scope` parameter.

Reference from:

[Storing Refresh Token In JavaScript, Getting New Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620692/storing-refresh-token-in-javascript-getting-new-access-token)

Comment: I changed my request according that sample and make sure that my variables contain actual values(refresh_token, client_id) but still get an error without some description. I'm not sure, but probably it's for API 1.0? Is it working for you?

Comment: If you use Oauth2.0, you must add " token-type: Bearer ". And I'm sorry. you should add "  scope " parameter. P.S. Did you checked this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow.

Comment: Thank you for link, somehow I missed it. Tried to reproduce it in postman - it works. Looks like I can't mark sub-comment as an answer, so instead I'm marking the initial comment and adding an note to question.